# C++ library for laying out graphs

Tags: library, c++, graphs, drawing, visual-studio

I am looking for a C++ library to layout graphs (directed and undirected).

I know that I can google for them and I did but all I found are Boost libraries and ones that are compatible with Qt only. I want something that is easily accessible on latest versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [igraph](https://igraph.org/c/) and its [layout generators](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Layout.html).

The Pitch/Blurb on the homepage says:

> "igraph is a collection of network analysis tools with the emphasis on efficiency, portability and ease of use. igraph is open source and free. igraph can be programmed in R, Python, Mathematica **and C/C++.** "